# Is there such a thing as a 25mm crank puller?

Tags: crankset, tools, bmx

I have a BMX with a Primo Pro crank on it that I need to remove.

The thread in the crank arms that the crank puller would normally screw into has 25mm diameter but I only seem to be able to find 22mm crank pullers.

Do crank pullers come in different sizes or is there some sort of adapted that I can use with a standard crank puller?

Comment: Just about every crank puller I've seen has threads for two different sizes of threads.  Can't say what the common sizes are.

Comment: If the puller has access to the rear side of the crank you may be able to use a standard claw type puller. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abzieher#/media/File:Poelietrekker.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42415/do-crank-arm-pullers-vary-in-sizes-or-there-is-just-one-size?rq=1

Comment: @Carel great spotting!

Comment: @Criggie: Didn't it appear at you right, in the 'Related' column?

Comment: This question gets into the black hole of BMX crank puller intercompatibility and model specific designs that I glossed over (and also don't have all the answers for) in the other question. The way they're phrased make them look like the same question, but they're sort of not.

Comment: I had seen the question sighted as a duplicate but this, while similar, is indeed a different question

Comment: @carel a claw type puller looks like it could work :-)

Comment: I am a bit confused, do you actually have a tool that won't fit (please post a link), or are you simply looking to order a tool?

Comment: @Danielrhicks can you elaborate on the crank pullers with two sizes of thread? Are they bicycle specific?

Comment: @Swifty - Pretty much your standard crank puller, similar to [this one](https://www.parktool.com/product/crank-puller-for-splined-cranks-ccp-44), except that the threaded collar is removable and has two different sized threads on its two ends.  I would guess this was the norm for pullers made 20 years ago, but they have since gone out of style.

Comment: Also note that some cranks are "self-pulling" -- there is a hole in the threaded cap to allow the insertion of an allen wrench.  You unthread the fixing bolt against the (fairly substantial) cap and it pushes the crank arm off.

Comment: For some Sunny indoor cycles there's 24mm puller here https://zoovaa.com/products/24mm-crank-puller-for-cycle-bikes?_pos=1&_sid=77e0512d5&_ss=r however I'm still looking for a 25mm one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I googled around and could find no mention of a Primo-specific puller or any 25mm puller. The threads are curious; most cranks like this don't have them. Maybe there used to be a tool available for them, or maybe a hop-up kit with threaded-in caps.

These cranks are more or less Profile copies and as such, in lieu of any other recommended procedure or tool available, the implication is you remove them by taking a Profile crank tool, removing the sleeve from it (which is used during installation), removing one of the crank bolts and replacing it with the tool, and pounding on the end of the tool with a hammer to drive the spindle out of the crank splines.

Comment: Yeah, I've searched pretty extensively and couldn't find a specific tool, although I did see mentioned that other size used to exist and was hopeful one of these might fit.  Annoyingly, it seems the hit it with a hammer approach is the way forward, there's even tools that work this way - just seems a bit heavy handed.

Comment: @NickHolt It applies sharp side impacts to the bottom bracket bearings, which isn't ideal, but just kind of how it is with this type of crank.

Comment: Can you find a photo of the tool to add to answer?   Not sure if https://www.eciimports.com/assets/thumb/25TOOLCRANKP.jpg or https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31iwbE5HhHL._SX466_.jpg or https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1540/1049/products/648468_Image_1400x.jpg   (suspect middle one)

Comment: @Criggie the first video (https://www.ridebmx.com/how-to/use-bmx-crank-puller/) in Deleted User's answer seems to sum up the BMX crank removers I've found - they're basically a big bolt, which you hit with hammer!

Comment: @NickHolt Video links may vanish - whereas a still image uploaded to StackExchange's part of Imgur will be around as long as SE is.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue. The threads in the spindle are M15x1, and all of the Profile crank puller tools available have different threads (the closest one is M15x1.25). So, I'm stuck.

Comment: Following up on my comment above, I found two BMX crank tools with M15x1 thread meaning they will work on Primo Pro crank:  

1. BSD Substance tool (verified physically, I own one now)  
2. Odyssey Calibur **v1** tool (per Odyssey support... the v2 tool is different)